# Pandas assign second min value to column

Tags: python, pandas

have stuck with pandas.
I have `df` which contains every transaction (first column - index, sorted by time):

```
        email    date
43487   aaa     2017-10-11 08:28:39
42910   bbb     2017-09-24 07:49:52
45561   bbb     2017-12-03 11:03:56
47212   bbb     2018-01-02 12:25:52
89734   ccc     2018-02-02 12:25:52
89734   ccc     2018-03-02 12:20:52
```

I also have `df2` which contains unique emails and min date (`df1` with drop_duplicates, since it was sorted by time, i got min date by default):

```
        email    date
43487   aaa     2017-10-11 08:28:39
42910   bbb     2017-09-24 07:49:52
89734   ccc     2018-02-02 12:25:52
```

How to create column `date2` in `df2`, containing the second min date for respective email in `df1`?

I tried `for` loop:

```
for email in df2['email']:
    df2.at[email, 'date2'] = df1.loc[df1['email'] == email]['date'].iloc[1] 
    if len(df1.loc[df1['email'] == email]['date']) > 1 else None
```

But it is very long (55k rows and 32 GB RAM - no result in 5 min).

Desired output is:

```
        email   date                date 2
43487   aaa     2017-10-11 08:28:39 None
42910   bbb     2017-09-24 07:49:52 2017-12-03 11:03:56
89734   ccc     2018-02-02 12:25:52 2018-03-02 12:20:52
```

Comment: Why first value of `date2` column is `None`?

Comment: Because there is only one `aaa` transaction, there was no second one.

Comment: So, basically, I want a table with 3 columns - `email`, `date of 1 transaction`, `date of 2 transactions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort the `dates` within each `email`, which can be done using a list of columns to sort by.

Then you `GroupBy` `email` and use [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) to select the second element of each group.

```
date2 = df.sort_values(['email','date']).groupby('email').nth(1)

             date
email                    
bbb   2017-12-03 11:03:56
ccc   2018-03-02 12:20:52
```

Finally left merge with `df2` on `email`:

```
df2.merge(date2, on = 'email', how = 'left')

    email        date_x              date_y
0   aaa 2017-10-11 08:28:39                 NaT
1   bbb 2017-09-24 07:49:52 2017-12-03 11:03:56
2   ccc 2018-02-02 12:25:52 2018-03-02 12:20:52
```